# Falta de tradução Title do icone de melhor resposta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

O `title` do span que aparece ícone de resposta aceita (o `v` verde) ainda está em inglês

Não sei se isso ajuda mas a class do span é `vote-accepted-on`

> **The question owner accepted this as the best answer** 21 mins atrás

Comment: Estava editando isso :) malz